# Understanding how to hook up "sent actions" in IOS Xcode to storyboard bar button item

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to use the **Core Data** example found on **iPhone Recipes** App example to create a **Core Data** base for my App.

I've painstakingly duplicated all `RecipeListTableViewControler`, and there is an + or "*add button in the corner*," which trigger a modal segue to the screen which adds the name of a new recipe.

However, there is also a sent action "add:" linked to the `RecipeListTableViewController`, and I've spent a couple of hours trying to figure out how to duplicate this for my `Storyboard`, and I'm stumped.

Could someone help me figure this out?

Thanks.

[image]

I know how to link an outlet from the storyboard to the code, by control dragging from the button to the code, or from one view controller to another to create the segue.  However, in this case I'm not finding a place on the storyboard that is linked to the sent action add as shown in the connections inspector.  Also, there is not a radio button in the code that seems to be linked to this add: action in the example.  As a result, I'm having trouble duplicating this same sent action to my code.  I can't make the sent action appear as part of my add button in my connections inspector:

[image]

I suppose I'm expecting that when I mouse over the connections inspector item, something will get highlighted in blue on the button, the view controller, or I'll see a radio button acting area in the code, but I'm not getting any hints about how to connect this up when I try that.

Note: When I examined the connections inspector for the tableviewcontroller, I found out that the add: bar button item on the view controller is showing as undefined, so it may not be linked up to anything, and that's why it was confusing me why I couldn't find a link between it and the code.

Comment: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch07.html#_action_connections

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2

Comment: checked these references, but they don't show me how to hook this up, they just show how to link a button to code.  In the example recipe app, there doesn't seem to be a radio button link in the code, although there is a reference to add in the "prepare for segue" section, but no radio button for a link there.

Comment: The apeth reference worked for me. First, in the code for the controller, I added: - (IBAction)addButtonPressed:(id)sender { /* your code here */ } Then, back in the storyboard, I selected the button, then, in the Utilities section on the right, I selected the Connections Inspector (a right arrow in a circle), or you could right-click on the button, then dragged from the Sent Actions select circle to the controller in the storyboard having the bar and button, and selected the action that I wanted to cause, in this case addButtonPressed.